# "Sharing With Controller" Vulnerability

Tags: apex, security-review

I got a "Sharing with Controller" Vulnerability from the Checkmarx scan. It doesn't give many details though it only flags this line in my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="CustomSettingController">
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to go on here, but I'm guessing that your controller is not declared using the `with sharing` keywords, and therefore isn't using the system's sharing model:

```
public with sharing class CustomSettingController
{
}
```

This enforces `sharing rules` which would otherwise be bypassed. You'll also need to manually enforce CRUD permissions in order to pass security review as this is **not** handled by the sharing model.

Comment: Meaning every time I do a CRUD action in my (with sharing) controller I need to check for the requisite isCreatable() isUpdateable() etc?

Comment: Technically, but what you can do is do all the checks in an `Init()` method, then display a message and lock down the page if the requirements aren't met. This doesn't make for the world's best user experience, but it's acceptable for security review and chances are you're going to want people to have all or nothing anyway.